# selenium - Need to find an element from a dynamically loaded division and click on it

Tags: java, selenium

Hi I am trying automate the below hybrid app stuff...writing test with selenium java, I just wanted to click on the  button only for specific app name..

[image: my code]

Comment: Code i have given as image ........please help

Comment: What is hybrid app stuff?

Comment: I am trying to automate a android - hybrid application.I have a division button with a custom attribute <div class="app-open-btn" appName="<%- app.APP_NAME %>">Open</div> ---- and I am trying locate this element by below code with selenium webdriver like below -driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@_appName='YMS']"))---I am getting no element found error

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xpath is working fine.
Check this out 
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ee704ab13cc47a875598406d380db68e

After your script <%- app.APP_NAME %> is getting executed... are you getting appName='YMS' ?

Comment: Yes I am getting I can see the app displayed on the screen, after that only I am executing the above text

Comment: I would suggest using Implicit wait before you execute your xpath.  ---driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Still it says unable to locate the element...driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@_appName = 'ReceivingSstkClient']")).click();

Comment: Do you think any option like we can have a condition check to find a specific app name from the dynamically loaded list and click on the open button corresponding to that, please see my above first scriprt

Comment: This issue is resolved             List < WebElement > productivityButtons = driver.findElements(By.className("app-open-btn"));
   for (WebElement item: productivityButtons) {
    String appName = item.getAttribute("appName");
    if (item.getAttribute("appName").equals("ReceivingSstkClient")) {
     item.click();
     
    } else {
     System.out.println("**Not matching");
    }